# I'd like to kill a session after a user has been inactive for 20 minutes. in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

I'd like to kill a session after a user has been inactive for 20 minutes.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Answer (score 3):

Build this into your code wherever appropriate:

`session_start();`

// 20 mins in seconds
$inactive = 1200;
$session_life = time() - $_session['timeout']; 
if($session_life > $inactive) {
   session_destroy(); header("Location: logoutpage.php");
}
$_session['timeout']=time();

This will check how much time has passed since the last request, if it is greater than 20 minutes it is destroyed.

Comment: This will probably redirect as soon as you login. If you add a check to makes sure the timeout variable exists before it checks for inactivity it should work better.
`if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
 $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
 if($session_life > $inactive)
        { session_destroy(); header("location: somelocation.php"); }
}`

Answer (score -4):

PHP will kill a session automatically after 24 min of inactivity.
I doubt 4 min makes so much difference.
Just use default settings and you'll be fine, no special actions needed.

Comment: Thats not really a fair thing to say.  What if an organization has a policy for 20 minutes of inactivity until their on-line management system should log them out.  Can you justify saying 24 minutes is better because it is easier to configure?